# rsyslog Disable $RepeatedMsgReduction for specific filter

Tags: server, 13.10, rsyslog

I have the following in my **rsyslog** configuration. It works well.

```
:msg, contains, "<switch2>" /var/log/switch.log
& ~
```

I need to disable RepeatedMsgReduction for log messages that are routed by this rule, while leaving it enabled for all other messages.

How can I do this?

*(originally asked in ServerFault but no responses)*

Answer (score -2):

Edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

and change `RepeatedMsgReduction` from `on` to `off`.

Comment: This answer doesn't meet the OPs original specification of "leaving it enabled for all other messages."